# W3 automatic slideshow converted to React (gatsbyjs)

Tags: javascript, beginner, react.js, gatsby

The original Javascript slider is on W3 schools. I modified it to work as a slider for my homepage. The goal is to call it into `index.js` (which works) and use it at the top of the page (which works) and if I want to swap out an image, I could load `slideshow.js`, add a new static image or remove an old one (also works).

But I bet it isn't really "React ready" as many tutorials have multiple components and GraphQL calls in them.

How can I make this better?

Oh yeah, Gatsby version 3.0.0 and `gatsby-starter-default` is the base.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { slideshow_wrapper } from "./slideshow.module.css";
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

const SlideShow = () => {
    let myIndex = 0;
    const showNextSlide = () => {
    let i;
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {
        myIndex = 1;
    }
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
};
React.useEffect(() => {
    showNextSlide()
    const i = setInterval(showNextSlide, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(i)
}, [])
return (
<div className={slideshow_wrapper}>
    <StaticImage
        src="../../images/slides/home_slider_1.jpg"
        width={1920}
        quality={100}
        formats={["AUTO", "WEBP", "AVIF"]}
        alt="A Gatsby astronaut"
        className="mySlides"
    />
    <StaticImage
        src="../../images/slides/home_slider_2.jpg"
        width={1920}
        quality={100}
        formats={["AUTO", "WEBP", "AVIF"]}
        alt="A Gatsby astronaut"
        className="mySlides"
    />
    </div>
    );
};

export default SlideShow;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your post looks good, I wonder though if you couldn't include a link to a fully working version to check out, since it's impossible to actually run it like this. Otherwise, hope you get some good answers anyway!